# Why in socket io they having set of script lines in html page?

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I am trying to develop a flutter chat app using nodejs and socketio.i'm just getting started with the socketio i have surf several examples in which every front end or client side having a set of socketio script. Can i develop my code purely server side? so that i can integrate with any type of front end.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that. `Socket.io` is a web socket implementation in node js. It enables real-time, bidirectional and event-based communication between client and server.

[image]

`Server` and `client` can send and receive the events. If you don't want write any script in client side then you don't have any use of `sockets`.

**Edit:**
`socket.io` given nice example for chat application with explanation. https://socket.io/get-started/chat/

Comment: I don't believe that's true... socket.io uses websockets when applicable, but maintains its own interface. And [sockets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket) have more do to with web requests, which are agnostic when it comes to programming languages, than they have to do with Javascript. There are socket.io clients for many non-web languages, [including C++](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-client-cpp).

Comment: Thanks a lot.Can i use those client side script in any front end ?such as angular,react,flutter etc..

Comment: @JoshuaT `socket.io` will not use web socket always. It'll use use  AJAX long-polling sometimes based on the internet connect. My point is why you need write the client side script. Not explaining how web sockets works.

Comment: @JeyamThillai you can listen and emit events in both client and server side.

Comment: @SarathKumar which method will you suggest to develop a chat application with node js ?

Comment: please follow the link. socket.io given nice example for chat application with explanation. https://socket.io/get-started/chat/

Answer (score 0):

Socket.io has two distinct parts - the [server](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io) and the client. The docs [make this clear](https://socket.io/get-started/chat/#Integrating-Socket-IO). There is nothing preventing you from just writing the server part, and leaving the client implementation out of the equation, for someone else to implement.

Although the main point of Socket.io is to implement the WebSocket protocol, it does so by wrapping it in its own interface, so to speak. So a socket.io server **can only talk to socket.io clients**, not clients that implement WebSocket in other ways. That being said, there are socket.io client libraries for pretty much every major language out there:

- [Javascript (main client)](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-client)
- [Java](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-client-java)
- [C++](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-client-cpp)
- [Dart/Flutter](https://github.com/rikulo/socket.io-client-dart)

You also asked about React and Angular, but both of those are web front-ends, so there should be no reason why they can't use the standard Javascript client library with those frameworks.